# Why is my instance variable changing indirectly?

Tags: ruby

I'm a starter at ruby, and I'm really stuck with this code... I can't understand why is @plays changing when a call test_code

```
class Board
  attr_reader :plays

  def initialize(secret_code)  
    @secret_code = secret_code
    @plays = []               
  end

  def insert_code(code)  
    @plays.push(code)          
    p @plays         #-> [["red", "red", "red", "red"]]
    test_code(code)  #-> When i call this method the changes on 'code' make to '@plays' array...
    p @plays         #-> [["check", "red", "red", "red"]]
  end

  private

  def test_code(code)
    s_code = @secret_code  # made a copy of @secret_code to keep it intact but is changing just like @plays
    s_code.each_index do |i|
      if s_code[i] == code[i]
        s_code[i] = "O"
        code[i] = "check"  #in this line the @plays array is changed, and i can't figure out why
      end
    end
  end
end

board = Board.new(["red", "blue", "blue", "blue"])
board.insert_code(["red", "red", "red", "red"])
```

Comment: I can't figure it out. Don't call the `test_code` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is a simplification of the real code... a need that function.... Well i could work out the code so i don't need to change the variable, but im really curious about the reason for this bug

Comment: Nitpicking, but the instance variable does not change, it still refers to the very same object. It's the object that is being changed.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator `=` does not make a copy of an object. It makes a new reference (i.e., pointer) to the object.

You can use `clone` to create a shallow copy of an object as follows:

```
...
s_code = @secret_code.clone
...
def test_code(code0)
  code = code0.clone
...
```

Comment: But why that doesn't happen normally? If a assign a variable  (a = b) and change the value of 'b' it doesn't change 'a'... Whats the difference?
And how can I assign the value of code to the @plays array without linking them?

Comment: That's only correct for simple values like integers. otherwise, `a=b` results in a and b referring to the same object. Read up on the difference between values and references. [Variable References and Mutability of Ruby Objects](https://launchschool.com/blog/references-and-mutability-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks for the help and patience, I will read more and work on the code. I just started programming, so I'm trying to understand the bugs i get. Really impressed with this community and it's willing to help  =)

Answer (score 0):

you defined the @plays like this:

```
  def insert_code(code)  
    @plays.push(code)          # here is not a clone but a quote
  end
```

after running the methond "test_code", the variable "code" is changed to ["check", "red", "red", "red"]
so you see the @plays is also changed to [["check", "red", "red", "red"]]

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but how can i pass the value of code to the array and not the variable it self. This doesn't happens normally in my codes, when i assign a variable "a" to a variable "b = 4" what happens is that the value of "b" (4) passes to "a", so when i change b it doesn't change "a". Whats special about my case?

Comment: For the simple values like integers, it's true the value pass to variable. Please see the comments by Jim U.

Comment: but for the rest scenarios, Ruby passes the quote to the variable. If you want to pass the value, you can use the "clone" or "dup" method. See below:

code = ["red", "blue", "blue", "blue"]
plays = code.clone  # or plays = code.dup
code[0] = "indigo"
p plays   #=> ["yellow", "blue", "blue", "blue"]